# First level caching and flushing hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, caching, jpa

Hello I have the following question. Lets suppose that we have Object User object with One to Many Lazy relation to Account. Now lets suppose that we have repeatable reads within one transaction to User and on one of the calls we have initialized the Accounts.

Now we delete one of the Accounts but we do not update the collection in User holding the accounts.

Now if we execute another repeatable read that is hitting the first level cache, will this read return updated number of Accounts - 1 less because we have deleted 1 of the Account.

If we execut flush will this make any difference? Thanks